# What's the best way to sync row data in two tables in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have two tables, to make it easy, consider the following as an example.

- contacts (has name and email)
- messages (messages but also has name and email w/c needs to be synced to the contacts table)

now please, for those who are itching to say "use relational method" or foreign key etc. I know, but this situation is different. I need to have a "copy" of the name and email of the messages on the messages table itself and need to sync it from time to time only.

As per the syncing requirement, I need to sync the names on the messages with the latest names on the contacts table.

I basically have the following UPDATE SQL in a loop for all rows in Contacts table

```
UPDATE messages SET name=(
SELECT name FROM contacts WHERE email = '$cur_email')
WHERE email='$cur_email'
```

the above loops through all the contacts and is fired as many contacts as I have.

I have several looping ideas to do this as well without using internal `SELECT` but I just thought the above would be more efficient (is it?), but I was wondering if there's an SQL way that's more efficient? Like:

```
UPDATE messages SET name=(
SELECT name FROM contacts WHERE email = '$cur_email')
WHERE messages.email=contacts.email
```

something that looks like a join?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be more efficient

```
UPDATE messages m  JOIN contacts n  on  m.email=n.email SET m.name=n.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. i figured it out now.. using JOINS on update

like:

```
UPDATE messages JOIN contacts ON messages.email=contacts.email
SET messages.email = contacts.email
WHERE messages.email != contacts.email
```

it's fairly simple!

BUT... I'm not sure if this is really the ANSWER TO MY POST, since my question is what the "BEST WAY is" in terms of efficiency..

Executing the above query on 2000 records took my system a 4second pause.. where as executing a few select , php loop, and a few update statements felt like it was faster..

hmmmmm

------ UPDATE --------

Well i went ahead and created 2 scripts to test this ..

on my QuadCore i7 Ivybridge machine, surprisingly

a single Update query via SQL JOIN is MUCH SLOWER than doing a rather multi query and loop approach..

on one side i have the above simple query running on 1000 records, where all records need updating...

script execution time was 4.92 seconds! and caused my machine to hicup for a split second.. noticed a 100% spike on one of my cores..

succeeding calls to the script (where no fields where needing update) took the same amount of time! ridiculous..

The other side, involving SELECT JOIN query to all rows needing an update, and a simple UPDATE query looped in a foreach() function in PHP..

took the script 
3.45 seconds to do all the updates..  @ around 50% single core spike
and
1.04 seconds on succeeding queries (where no fields where needing update)

Case closed...

hope this helps the community!

ps
This is what i meant when debating some logic with programmers who are too much into "coding standards".. where their argument is "do it on the SQL side" if you can as it is faster and more of the standard rather than crude method of evaluating and updating in loops w/c they said was "dirty" code.. sheesh.